# XMLHttpRequest is being cancelled by Safari though i see a 200 OK response on the wire

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest

I'm using an XHR to grab some resources via a content script in a Safari extension.  I get an error loading the resources and in the web inspector menu I see the request has status canceled.  I'm also sniffing the network and I see the request successfully completing and the data being sent back with a 200 OK.  I've been stuck on this forever and I'm at a bit of a loss as to what could be cancelling the request. Any ideas?

I don't want to post full logs as this is sensitive data, but I'm happy to provide more info as needed.